# Nvenc session limit per GPU

Tags: python, ffmpeg, python-imageio, nvenc

I'm using Imageio, the python library that wraps around ffmpeg to do hardware encoding via nvenc. My issue is that I can't get more than 2 sessions to launch (I am using non-quadro GPUs). Even using multiple GPUs. I looked over NVIDIA's support matrix and they state only 2 sessions per gpu, but it seems to be per system.

For example I have 2 GPUs in a system. I can either use the env variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES or set the ffmpeg flag -gpu to select the GPU. I've verified gpu usage using Nvidia-smi cli. I can get 2 encoding sessions working on a single gpu. Or 1 session working on 2 separate gpus each. But I can't get 2 encoding sessions working on 2 gpus.

Even more strangely if I add more gpus I am still stuck at 2 sessions. I can't launch a third encoding session on a 3rd gpu. I am always stuck at 2 regardless of the # of gpus. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: This is the working patch removing limitation https://github.com/keylase/nvidia-patch
It even works with Docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nvidia limits it 2 per system Not 2 per GPU. The limitation is in the driver, not the hardware. There have been unofficially drivers posted to github which remove the limitation

Comment: Ty, been trying to get this to work. Nice to know its not possible.